# Writes to an automounted directory are extremely slow

Tags: centos, nfs, automounting

Writes on an automounted filesystem take an extremely long time. Whether it's a

```
mvn clean
```

or a

```
tar -xvzf hugetarball.tar.gz
```

the operation takes 15 minutes for every 1 minute the operation would take on a local filesystem.

```
OS: CentOS 7.3
NFS mounted filesystem
Distance: 0 hops. All machines are on the same VLAN, same subnet. 
Automount Information: -rw,hard,nolock,noac,vers=3,tcp
```

Comment: You've tagged with [tag:nfs] so should we assume that your automounted filesystem is an NFS filesystem? If so, please say so. In network terms how far away is your NFS server? What mount options have you used? What export options have you used? Please [edit your question to include this information](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/379608/edit).

Comment: How do you know the problem isn't caused by NFS server performance? It's the first item I would check.

Comment: 100Mbit or 1Gbit network? Faster? Same VLAN and same subnet doesn't say how far away the systems are from each other. I could have a VLAN spanning the globe (I do) and it would have a RTT of 250+ms. That's slow compared to two systems in the same datacentre also on a same subnet. Where are your read/write buffer size adjustments for a fast network? What settings do you have in `/etc/exportfs` for this share? What server (Linux/Unix/Windows/Other) is providing the NFS service? Does the hugetarball.tar.gz reside on the NFS share? Are you also extracting the tarball contents to the NFS share?